# WPF ObservableCollection Updating DataGrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I am trying to reflect an `ObservableCollection` changes in `DataGrid`.
My problem is that `DataGrid` dont show changes when i add new element in collection there is no new row in `DataGrid`.
This is `ViewModel` class that is bind to Window

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Configuration> configuration;
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        configuration = new ObservableCollection<Model.Configuration>();
    } 
public ObservableCollection<Configuration> Configuration { 
                get { return configuration; } 
                set { configuration = value; 
                      OnProperyChanged("Configuration"); 
                 }}
 #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnProperyChanged(string propertyChanged)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChanged));
        }
    }
    #endregion}
```

And my `DataGrid` is

```
<DataGrid x:Name="maintable" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="180" Margin="10,61,391,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="300"  Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Please go into detail about what results you're seeing, any errors, etc. (I assume you prematurely cut off the XAML for your DataGrid since you're at the very least missing some closing tags.)

Comment: My problem is that DataGrid dont show changes when i add new element in collection there is no new row in DataGrid.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but did you set the view model as the data context? All I see is a view model and a control, but have no idea if you wired them up to each other.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with the code or XAML that was shown. Therefore, I did a test project. I cannot duplicate the problem. The code that you provided doesn't show how you're adding new Configuration instances. Please add that so I can take a look at it.

Comment: To add onto what Jeff stated, you should see data binding errors in the Output window if you didn't set your view-model to your DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

From some reason in `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` it was needed to add `Mode=OneWay` and now DataGrid is updating when ObservableCollection is changed

```
<DataGrid x:Name="maintable" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="180" Margin="10,61,391,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="300"  Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
```

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you, but there's something else at play. First of all, the binding direction only affects the Configuration property -- not its items. That's being set, but doesn't change. Second, I'm using the default mode which is two-way and my example works just fine.